# iText7 missing GetPageSizeWithRotation and GetOverContent

Tags: c#, itext7

In iText7 I dont see a `GetPageSizeWithRotation` or `GetOverContent` method. Is there another way to do this ?

New Code

```
PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
Rectangle pageSizeWithRotation = pdfPage.GetPageSizeWithRotation();
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfPage);
```

Old Code

```
Rectangle pageSizeWithRotation = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i);
PdfContentByte overContent = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(i);
float n3 = pageSizeWithRotation.Height - 10F;
```

Comment: So you meanwhile have found `GetPageSizeWithRotation` and also seen how to get a `PdfCanvas` to draw stuff over the existing page content, it looks like your original question is answered and you're ready to go. In asking for "another way to do this", what advantages do you hope for, in what way does your way not do what you hope for?

Comment: I dont see this `pageSizeWithRotation.Height` object.

Comment: What have you tried? Every decent IDE will easily allow you to inspect the `Rectangle` class there and the `GetHeight()` method just leaps into one's eye...

Comment: Thanks I see that now